# Print a paragraph in perl by not formatting using escape sequence

Tags: perl, verification

I am using a existing Perl subroutine to print a file as following:

```
sub quit_FRM () {
print STDOUT <<QUIT_IDLE;

##-------------------------------------------------- 
## Quit idle
##--------------------------------------------------
Q idle

QUIT_IDLE

}
```

By calling this subroutine, it would print on stdout the following:

```
##-------------------------------------------------- 
## Quit idle
##--------------------------------------------------
Q idle
```

I have been searching on google for a while but I still had no clue. Can anybody tell me what is "<<" here? and what is "QUIT_IDLE" here? And hopefully I can search on google how to use this feature.

Right, this is a duplicated question, but by searching "perl print << " does not give anything relevant at all, or anything I can think of to describe this question.

Comment: It might interest you to know that while Perl supports this (heredocs), you can also just use normal quotes with newlines included. (I.e. replace `<<QUIT_IDLE` and `QUIT_IDLE` with `"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "here document". See [<<EOF](http://p3rl.org/perlop#%3c%3c_EOF_) in `perlop`.

It exists in other languages, too:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document

Comment: thanks! that's what i am looking for.